# Filter JSON Object based on internal array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have the following JSON object 
I need to filter the response based on the header and key of the inner array , such that `"ISVN8JF1E" == “key”: ISVN8JF1E`

```
{
  "1233-39CFBWYA": [],
  "JMSK0DKOE": [],
  "ISVN8JF1E": [
    {

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "LA",
      "hello": "OUTSIDE",
      "key": "ISVN8JF1E"
    },
    {
      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "Chicago",
      "hello": "Inside",
      "key": "ISVN8JF1E"
    },
    {
      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "Austin",
      "hello": "Inside",
      "key": "ABCDE"
    }
  ],
 "ISVN8JF1B": [
    {

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "LA",
      "hello": "OUTSIDE",
      "key": "ISVN8JF1B"
    },
    {
      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "Chicago",
      "hello": "Inside",
      "key": "ISVN8JF1C"
    },
    {
      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "Austin",
      "hello": "Inside",
      "key": "ABCDE"
    }
  ],
  "OGAESJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [],
  "SC9OMJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": []
  }
```

Here is what I tried :

var result = Object.keys(data).forEach(function (Id) {

```
                var updatedResult = {
                    [Id] : data[Id].filter(function (my) {
                        return my.key == Id;
                    })
                };

                totalResultArray.push(updatedResult);
            });
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: and the key is given?

Comment: yes key is provided

Comment: Sounds like a job for Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map ...Oops, I mean filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON array.

Comment: @trincot: There can/could be.

Comment: JSON is a data exchange format. The array is a JavaScript object that is derived from JSON. The array is not JSON, it is an object. A matter of using the term JSON correctly.

Comment: @trincot: Still it is possible to push JSON strings into an array = JSON array..

Comment: Please tell us what you tried so far and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the given key and filter if the key is set.

```js
var data = { "1233-39CFBWYA": [], "JMSK0DKOE": [], "ISVN8JF1E": [{ delloData: "1478644629", ref: "75", dataType: "String", somePart: "LA", hello: "OUTSIDE", key: "ISVN8JF1E" }, { delloData: "1478644629", ref: "75", dataType: "String", somePart: "Chicago", hello: "Inside", key: "ISVN8JF1E" }, { delloData: "1478644629", ref: "75", dataType: "String", somePart: "Austin", hello: "Inside", key: "ABCDE" }], "OGAESJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [], "SC9OMJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [] },
    key = 'ISVN8JF1E',
    result = (data[key] || []).filter(function (o) {
        return o.key === key;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var blob = {
  "1233-39CFBWYA": [],
  "JMSK0DKOE": [],
  "ISVN8JF1E": [{
    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "LA",
    "hello": "OUTSIDE",
    "key": "ISVN8JF1E"
  }, {
    "delloData ": "1478644629 ",
    "ref ": "75 ",
    "dataType ": "String ",
    "somePart ": "Chicago ",
    "hello ": "Inside",
    "key": "ISVN8JF1E"
  }, {
    "delloData ": "1478644629 ",
    "ref ": "75 ",
    "dataType ": "String ",
    "somePart ": "Austin ",
    "hello ": "Inside",
    "key": "ABCDE"
  }],
  "OGAESJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA ": [],
  "SC9OMJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA ": []
};

var match_key = "ISVN8JF1E";

var filtered = blob["ISVN8JF1E"].filter(function(val) {
  return val.key == match_key;
});

console.log(filtered);
```